# How to create a media notification for my webview?

Tags: java, android, webview, notifications, media

I'm making a browser and I need a media player that pops up in notifications when you turn on video or online audio, with the ability to rewind and pause, how can I implement this for my webview?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this layout.

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/mid_grey"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView25"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/pspdf__ic_sound" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:max="100"
            android:progress="25"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imageView25"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>
```

And use this in the JavaScript:

```
SeekBar seekBar = this.findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript(...); //call the javascript function set the volume to the new value
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```